# Strange behaviour in invoking closures

Tags: php, closures

I wonder why this does not work: (`PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method stdClass::y()`)

```
$x=new stdClass;
$x->y=function(){return 'hi';};
echo $x->y();
```

but this works:

```
$x=new stdClass;
$x->y=function(){return 'hi';};
$y=$x->y;
echo $y();
```

`echo ($x->y)();` also return `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';'` invalid. So, what is the correct way to call `y` closure property without the intermediate variables.

Comment: o.O this is some next level twisted usage

Comment: Alternative: `call_user_func($x->y)`.

Answer (score 4):

Because in PHP a class can have functions and properties, and functions and properties *may* have the same name.

So when you call:

```
$x->y();
```

PHP will look for a function on `$x` with the name `y`, and then call it. What you have instead is a property (which *holds* a function/closure).

This is different from say, javascript, where both functions and properties are in the same 'namespace'.